# debugger in php

Tags: php

What is the best way to create a breakpoint in my php code? What debugger should I use? I am using Dream Weaver cs5, with wamp server.

I want to check in my code if certain **function/code** is executed while running or not, by adding a breakpoint. Also please mention how to use that debugger.

Comment: Try to avoid asking general questions like "Tell me now to use that debugger." It's on you to figure out how to use it. Follow the documentation or find a tutorial.

Comment: Try ZendStudio  http://www.zend.com/products/studio/

Answer (score 1):

Look at [Xdebug](http://xdebug.org/)

Comment: Ok, if it works in dream weaver. All they say use zstudio or sth like that.

Comment: You might want to switch to Eclipse. There is a great support for mentioned Xdebug and you can toogle breakpoints with a mousclick.

Comment: Look for Wincachegrind.
xdebug can create a profiling snapshot on demand, you can open this with Wincachegrind and it will reveal the programflow and timings. A very useful tool. Breakpoints are often not the right thing for PHP, I only use "echo" like output and for harder tasks xdebug profiling.

Comment: @Maroe Eclipse is an other debugger, or i have to use xdebug for that. Because xdebug is not installing in my server. I have used the correct .dll for that but it dont.

Comment: Eclipse (or better the PDT Plugin for Eclipse) is an IDE aming for PHP and Web-related development. There you have a great debugging integration with xdebug.

Answer (score 0):

Look at [DBG](http://www.nusphere.com/products/php_debugger.htm)
you can set breakpoint in [IDE](http://www.nusphere.com/products/phped.htm), you can embed breakpoint by placing DebugBreak() that will call the IDE and finally you can setup debugger to trigger upon errors or certain exceptions (jit settings for debugger)